# "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'" - but I'm not using C# or asp.net, I'm the one making the request

Tags: java, asp.net, okhttp

I'm writing a Java app. When I try to make a request to an API using OkHttp, nothing is returned. When I went to the request URL in a browser, I got the response `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`

I can only find help online if you're the one hosting the server. Is there anything I, as the one making the request, can do? Or do I have to wait until the API people can fix it?

Comment: check if the request should be a POST/ PUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fool, you just assumed that the problem with your request was caused by the message in the browser! In actuality, it was a bug in your Android emulator. You simply needed to cold boot the emulated device, and it was fixed!